# Graphene with Flask doesn't load schema

Tags: python, flask, graphql, graphene-python

I'm trying to run [this example](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/sqlalchemy/en/latest/tutorial/) for using Graphene with Flask. I make the `models.py`, `schema.py`, and `app.py` verbatim from that page, and put them all in the `flask_sqlalchemy` folder, as instructed. Then I make and populate the database with the instructions listed at the bottom.

Everything was going ok until I tried to run `app.py`. When I did that it gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 6, in <module>
    from schema import schema, Department
  File "C:\Users\asdf\Python\GraphQL\flask_sqlalchemy\schema.py", line 7, in <module>
    schema = graphene.Schema()
  File "C:\Users\asdf\Envs\GraphQL\lib\site-packages\graphene\types\schema.py", line 27, in __init__
    ).format(query)
AssertionError: Schema query must be Object Type but got: None.
```

So basically it failed on the line in `schema.py` that says:

```
schema = graphene.Schema()
```

And indeed, if I open a command prompt and do this it fails the same way:

```
>>> import graphene
>>> s  = graphene.Schema()
Traceback... (same traceback)
```

I'm using Python 3.5 on Windows 10. The only difference from the tutorial is that I use [virtualenvwrapper-win](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win) instead of the regular virtualenv.

This is my first experience with graphene or graphql in general, and I'm sure it ends up being a stupid mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Ivan! Your response put me on the right track and I'd mark that as the correct answer, but the solution was even simpler.

`schema.py` in the tutorial is this:

```
# flask_sqlalchemy/schema.py
import graphene
from graphene import relay
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyObjectType, SQLAlchemyConnectionField
from models import db_session, Department as DepartmentModel, Employee as EmployeeModel

schema = graphene.Schema()

class Department(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = DepartmentModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Employee(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()
    all_employees = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(Employee)

schema.query = Query
```

But as Ivan pointed out, the `graphene.Schema()` function needs to be handed a query, so it fails at `schema = graphene.Schema()`. The easy solution is to move that line to the end and hand it the Query class, so change the file to:

```
# flask_sqlalchemy/schema.py
import graphene
from graphene import relay
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyObjectType, SQLAlchemyConnectionField
from models import db_session, Department as DepartmentModel, Employee as EmployeeModel

class Department(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = DepartmentModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Employee(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()
    all_employees = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(Employee)

schema = graphene.Schema(query = Query)
```

And then the example appears to work as intended. I think this is an error in the tutorial and should be changed on the Graphene website.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide at least a `query` object to your `schema` object, else there is nothing to "expose" through GraphQL.

```python
class Employee(SQLAlchemyObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    employee = graphene.Field(
        Employee, 
        employee_id=graphene.Argument(graphene.Integer)
    )

    def resolve_employee(self, args, context, info):
        """Resolves `employee` object on the root query"""
        employee_id = args.get('employee_id')
        employee = EmployeeModel.query.get(employee_id)
        return employee

# Provide the root query to schema
schema = graphene.Schema(query=query)
```